# how to customise x axis in jqPlot?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

there are 3 objects in my example, which are `A`,`B` and `C`. Each object contains N points. for example

[image]

```
A - 2 points
B - 2 points
C - 1 points
```

I need to show object name in X axis, the x value of name is same as x of first point in an object.

but I don't know how to design the data structure to hold data and show it in jqPlot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the objects in the array of arrays for jqplot as follows `[[A,1],[A,2],[B,1],[B,2],[C,1]]`